# Convert string to datetime ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this is basic but I've been struggling for a few hours now and I can't seem to apply one of the many ways there are to convert a string to datetime so I can save it in the database in this format `2018-03-16 00:12:17.555372`. Thanks ahead

This is the string output in the console.

```
params[:event][:start_date]
"03/28/2018 1:46 AM"
```

[EDIT] Following some leads I've come up with smething really dirty maybe someone can help refactor I'm supressing AM or PM because I don't know how to parse that I know it's awfull any help is appreciated!

```
  if !params[:event][:start_date].empty?
    start_date = params[:event][:start_date]
    start_date = start_date.gsub(/[AMP]/, '').squish 
    a = start_date.split('/')
    tmp = a[0]
    a[0] = a[1]
    a[1] = tmp   
    a = a.split(',').join('/')
    start_date = Time.parse(a)
  end

 if !params[:event][:end_date].empty?
   end_date = params[:event][:end_date]
   end_date = end_date.gsub(/[AMP]/, '').squish 
   a = end_date.split('/')
   tmp = a[0]
   a[0] = a[1]
   a[1] = tmp   
   a = a.split(',').join('/')
   end_date = Time.parse(a)
 end
```

Comment: Where does `params[:event][:start_date]` come from? Is it input from a HTML form, a date picker maybe? If so, you can probably change it to pass an ISO 8601 compliant string instead.

Comment: it's from bootstrap datetime picker within the formno idea how to change the string to be iso 8601 compliant do you have a resource you can link here @stefan ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) to parse the date from a specific format.

if the format you are looking to parse is "03/28/2018 1:46 AM" then you can do this.

```
date = DateTime.strptime('03/28/2018 1:46 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')

# date to ISO 8601

puts date.to_time
# output: 2018-03-28 07:16:00 +0530

puts date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
# output: 03/28/2018
```

Date formats:

```
Date (Year, Month, Day):

%Y - Year with century (can be negative, 4 digits at least)
        -0001, 0000, 1995, 2009, 14292, etc.
%m - Month of the year, zero-padded (01..12)
        %_m  blank-padded ( 1..12)
        %-m  no-padded (1..12)
%d - Day of the month, zero-padded (01..31)
        %-d  no-padded (1..31)

Time (Hour, Minute, Second, Subsecond):

%H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock, zero-padded (00..23)
%k - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock, blank-padded ( 0..23)
%I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock, zero-padded (01..12)
%l - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock, blank-padded ( 1..12)
%P - Meridian indicator, lowercase (``am'' or ``pm'')
%p - Meridian indicator, uppercase (``AM'' or ``PM'')

%M - Minute of the hour (00..59)
```

You can refer to all formats [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-iso8601).

Comment: Perfect works like a charm thanks for your help and explanation @Gautam Chibde

Answer (score 2):

You can parse it like so in ruby:

> Parses the given representation of date and time, and creates a DateTime object. This method does not function as a validator.

```
DateTime.parse('2001-02-03T04:05:06+07:00')
                          #=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T04:05:06+07:00 ...>
DateTime.parse('20010203T040506+0700')
                          #=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T04:05:06+07:00 ...>
DateTime.parse('3rd Feb 2001 04:05:06 PM')
                          #=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T16:05:06+00:00 ...>
```

Not entirely sure if the string you supplied can be parsed, here is the link to the ruby docs on datetimes [Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#M000485)

Comment: I'm trying and it's working kind of but I feel like it's wrong I'm chopin am or pm i edited the thread. Thanks @RickS